# IntelliJ refactoring to inline usage of a helper class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

I had a function which became too big, so I refactored variables into fields on a (new) class and parts of the method to methods on the class. My function now looks like this

```
void doSomething() {
    Resource resource = ....
    new HelperClass(resource)
          .doFirstThing()
          .doSecondThing()
          .closeResource();
```

Now I wish to do the inverse transformation (because the doSomething function is actually a testcase and I need to produce a nice linear testcase that I can post to Issue Tracker).

How do I do this using automatic refactoring tools in IntelliJ Idea Community?

Comment: I've removed the word "undo" from the question, because it moves attention from refactoring features to undo functionality. I solved my problem long time ago (using git revert, incidentally), now I am only interested in refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a direct undo is possible, but check the local history (right click -> Local History -> Show History) to view previous versions of the original class.    These versions will have been created automatically by IntelliJ when various events have occurred, including saving after changes.  You can then selectively restore the state you want

Comment: Reasonable solution. I have the original version in git, so as another alternative, I could restore from there. Or I could also manually perform the refactoring backwards.

Comment: Local history is typically a lot finer grained than git commits, because it versions as you work.